# Save dates in UTC

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm currently trying to save my dates in database with de UTC timezone.

To get the user timezone, I have a JS function that makes an AJAX request to my back-end like this :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import jstz from 'jstz';

export default function setSessionTimezone(route)
{
    var timezone = jstz.determine();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST', async:true, cache:false, url:route, data:"timezone="+timezone.name(),
        success:function(data) { if (data.reloadPage) location.reload(); }
    });
}
```

This method is called only if the timezone is not already in session.
So, for now, I have the user timezone in my back-end, that was the first step.

I want to save it in the database.
With this SO post, I found something interesting : [Symfony buildForm convert datetime to local and back to utc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36632816/symfony-buildform-convert-datetime-to-local-and-back-to-utc)

They recommend to use the "model_timezone" and "view_timezone" for the forms, so did I :

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TimeType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UtcTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * @var SessionInterface
     */
    private $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * Return the class of the type being extended.
     */
    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        return [TimeType::class, DateType::class];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'model_timezone' => 'UTC',
            "view_timezone" => $this->session->get('tools_timezone')
        ]);
    }
}
```

And hooora, it works.
But only within the forms.

If I want to display the dates with Twig or from PHP, I need to get the timezone from session and change the DateTime's Timezone.

So I searched another option.
I found [this on the Doctrine Website](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html#handling-different-timezones-with-the-datetime-type) to change the timezone directly from Doctrine.

This sound interesting, but I'm probably missing a point because it doesn't seem to work, even after I added the following configuration :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            datetime: SomeNamespace\DoctrineExtensions\DBAL\Types\UTCDateTimeType
```

So I would like to know **if what I want to do is even possible** ? Or if I'm forced to override Twig "date" filter to use my timezone ? And if I want to display a date from PHP, I'm also force to use the timezone from the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that seem to answer my question.

I added a listener to the doctrine's event "postLoad".

For information, the TimezoneProvider just return the DateTimezone object from the session or UTC if it was not defined.

```
use DateTime;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;
use SomeNamespace\Provider\TimezoneProvider;
use ReflectionClass;
use ReflectionException;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;

class DateTimeConverterListener
{
    /**
     * @var AnnotationReader
     */
    private $reader;

    /**
     * @var TimezoneProvider
     */
    private $timezoneProvider;

    public function __construct(AnnotationReader $reader, TimezoneProvider $timezoneProvider)
    {
        $this->reader = $reader;
        $this->timezoneProvider = $timezoneProvider;
    }

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        $propertyAccessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();

        try {
            $reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class($entity));

            //We search the properties where we need to update the Timezone.
            foreach ($reflection->getProperties() as $property) {
                $annotation = $this->reader->getPropertyAnnotation($property, Column::class);
                if (!$annotation instanceof Column)
                    continue;

                switch ($annotation->type) {
                    case "time":
                    case "date":
                    case "datetime":
                        /** @var DateTime|null $attribute */
                        $attribute = $propertyAccessor->getValue($entity, $property->getName());

                        if (null === $attribute)
                            continue 2;

                        //The getTimezone function returns UTC in case of no session information. And because it's a
                        // DateTime object, we don't need to set the value after the modification
                        $attribute->setTimezone($this->timezoneProvider->getTimezone());
                        break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
            //Abort the transformation
        }
    }
}
```

To display the date properly with the twig filter "|date", I also update Twig through an event :

```
use SomeNamespace\Provider\TimezoneProvider;
use Twig\Environment;
use Twig\Extension\CoreExtension;

class SetupTwigTimezoneListener
{
    /**
     * @var TimezoneProvider
     */
    private $timezoneProvider;
    /**
     * @var Environment
     */
    private $twig;

    public function __construct(TimezoneProvider $timezoneProvider, Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->timezoneProvider = $timezoneProvider;
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest()
    {
        //Define the timezone of the application based of the timezone of the user
        $this->twig->getExtension(CoreExtension::class)->setTimezone($this->timezoneProvider->getTimezone()->getName());
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure this is a perfect solution, but it seem to work.